# How to write array out to spreadsheet. setValues throws "cannot convert array to object"

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write my array out to a spreadsheet but I am doing something wrong.  I have read many posts that say to do what I am doing but it is not working.   See my last line of code below

on the very last line of code
'''consol_sheet.getRange(2,1,x,10).setValues(final_values);'''
I get an error that I

> "cannot convert array to  object"

```
function iterateSheets() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('filesSheet');
  sh.clear();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1axTLHOBPhl5_u7ngFOxViHg14OSw7pVC');//replace id with actual id of folder
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var consol_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18JnkQYa1L-FhXFmKJBrqJ6GI7BBO-V8QAVKP8PLLoXo').getActiveSheet();
  var x=2;
  var z=0;
  var final_values = new Array(50000);

while(files.hasNext())
 {
   var file=files.next();
    var ts=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    var allShts=ts.getSheets();

       for(var i=0;i<3;i++)   //allShts.length   
       {  
            var consol_values = allShts[i].getRange(8,1,40,26).getValues();  //.getRange(8, 1, 1, 1).getValues();
            var headers = allShts[i].getRange(7,6,1,20).getValues();  //.getRange(8, 1, 1, 1).getValues();
            var position= allShts[i].getRange("B1").getValue();
            var period = allShts[i].getRange("B2").getValue();
            var email = allShts[i].getRange("B3").getValue();    

         for (var z = 0;z<20;z++)//
         {   

           for (var y= 0;y<40;y++)              
           {          
               if (consol_values[y][i] != "")
               {
              /*  consol_sheet.getRange(x,1).setValue(consol_values[y][0]);  //AI pack 
                consol_sheet.getRange(x,3).setValue(consol_values[y][1]); //measure
                consol_sheet.getRange(x,4).setValue(email);
                consol_sheet.getRange(x,5).setValue(position);     


                final_values[x] = [];
                final_values[x][0]  =consol_values[y][0];  //AI pack 
                 //blank
                final_values[x][2]  =(consol_values[y][1]); //measure
                final_values[x][3]  =(email);
                final_values[x][4]  =(position);     
                final_values[x][5]  =(headers[0][z]);//location
                final_values[x][6]  =1;
                final_values[x][7]  =(period);
                final_values[x][8]  =(consol_values[y][3]); //price
                final_values[x][9]  =(consol_values[y][z+5]); //fcst

                if (consol_values[y][z+5] != "")
                { 
                    final_values[x][10] =(consol_values[y][25]); //fcst value             
                }                          


                x = Number(x)+1  //row count for consolidation output

              }
          }          
         }    
      }
    }


consol_sheet.getRange(2,1,x,10).setValues(final_values);

 }
```

This forum has been extremely helpful in getting me to this point now I just have one more hurdle here to finish this project.

Comment: `x` starts at 2. What happened to 0, 1 and 2? `final_values[0]` will be `undefined` so are indexes 1 and 2. And there must be 50k elements as you've declared that  this array has 50k elements.

Comment: setting x = 0 fixed my length issue.   I will work on the blanks now.

Comment: just declare it as a empty array. `var final_values = []`

Comment: I did that in my code so I am guessin the blank is now my issue.

Answer (score 3):

The argument of `setValues` should be an array of arrays (2D Array) where all the inner arrays have the same number of elements and those elements should be strings, numbers or Date objects, there can't be empty elements.

NOTE:

If your array look like this

```
[
  [1,,'orange'], // 2nd element of this inner array is empty
  , // 2nd element of the outer array is empty
  [] // This array is empty
]
```

add the missing inner arrays and `''` on each "empty spot" of the inner arrays. The resulting  array should look like this:

```
[
  [1,'','orange'],
  ['','',''],
  ['','','']
]
```

(add an empty string `''` on each empty element place).

Related

- [How to write an array to Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27256238/1595451)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I feel like I am doing exactly what is presented in this link.    When you say no empty elements, I am have a lot of empty elements because of the nature of my data.   I am not sure I can eliminate them but I will give it a try.

Comment: @datafarmer I added a note to my answer. Hopefully it make what I tried to said more clear.

Comment: I figured the best way to do this was to write a formula like this--   if (consol_values[y][0].length != 0 ) {consol_values[y][0];}  else  {"";}  but when I set this = to a variable I get an error.   how do you suggest I write blank values in to the null array elements??

Answer (score 0):

**Writing Rows and Columns to a Spreadsheet**

Here's a simple function that writes rows and columns out to a spreadsheet.

```
function writeRowColToSpreadsheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clear();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,25,25);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      vA[i][j]=Utilities.formatString('%s,%s', i+1,j+1);
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Cooper, thanks for your input I have tried this exact code and get an error on the second part of the getRange final_value[0] and that is why I hard coded the value.  The error I get is TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.

Comment: That means you definitely don't have a 2-d array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making your modifications to the original 2d array you pulled, consol_values? That way you'll know you have the same number of elements you expect. you can start your loops at somewhere other than 0/1 depending on what values from the original you want to ignore (your pull area isn't quite the same as your write area in this case).